# Implementation of PlatformTransactionManager

Tags: spring, spring-transactions

Suppose I have some third party library and I want to integrate it with Spring in order to be able to use it as a part of Spring transaction. I didn't find any relevant information on the Internet and looked into the source code of integrations of RabbitMQ and MyBatis libraries. As I understood from their source code I should implement `org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager` and interact with `TransactionSynchronizationManager`. And there are two questions:

1. How Spring "know" about and instanciate implementations of `PlatformTransactionManager`?
2. Suppose there are two resources been used in transaction through `RabbitTemplate` and
   `JdbcTemplate`. What will be first committed - changes in database or
   messages sent?

Also, I would be really appreciate if somebody point me out to some guide or book about interactions with Spring internals.

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to instantiate them yourself, like a DataSourceTransactionManager or a HibernateTransactionManager. Spring Boot does that for you under the hood, but with plain Spring you need to do it yourself.
2. What you want are distributed transactions (XADataSource), which are not possible with RabbitMQ.
3. For RabbitMQ you should read this here first: https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html . Then make sure you understand transactions on the JDBC side. Then you can reason about how they both work together.
4. For the Java side, you might enjoy this book entirely about transactions: https://www.marcobehler.com/books/1-java-database-connections-transactions